# button.setOnClick Action Android

Tags: android, button

I have a button, and when the button is pressed an action will start. But only one action is starting, the second action isn't working. 
Here is my code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) red.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += 1;
            red.requestLayout();
            ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) blue.getLayoutParams()).topMargin -= 1;
            blue.requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

When i hit the button, "blue" always works, but red never does.    I can't find anything in the code...

Comment: It works if i make the '+= 1' both the same... But it doesn't work if i "+=1 and -=1"

Comment: what are you saying sir

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?